# Django - Combine City, State & Zipcode into single field

Tags: python, django, user-interface

Has anyone successfully done this?

Trying to replicate functionality similar to what is found at
http://www.walmart.com/cservice/ca_storefinder.gsp

Where the user can enter either a city, state or zipcode and have an intelligent lookup

I started an attempt using a bit of regex and splitting fields though I quickly realized this was a task that would take more than a little bit of thought to make it work intelligently for the end user

approaches considered

- live ajax auto-complete calls
- Sphinx full text search
- regex search db side
- regex validate user input

snippet thus far below

```
import re

from general.models import ZipCode

def findLocation(value):
    match = re.search(r"\d{5}", value)
    if match:
        try:
            return Zipcode.objects.get(zip=value)
        except ZipCode.DoesNotExist:
            return False
    else:
        kwargs = {}
        vals = value.split(',')
        if len(vals) > 1:
            kwargs['city'] = value[:len(value)-len(vals[-1])-1]
            state = vals[-1].strip()
            if len(state) == 2:
                kwargs['state'] = state
                else:
                kwargs['state_name'] = state
        else:
            kwargs['city'] = value
        return ZipCode.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

ZipCode in this example is a database model that contains a all US zip codes / states / state abbreviations / cities
there is a copy available on github at

https://github.com/amites/django-general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of advanced feature, you'd better use some dedicated tool, like [the Solr search engine](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

If you don't know it, it's a java based, open-source, very powerful search engine, with the ability to add location search features. The search actions will be performed through a web service (xml, json, etc.)

The steps are basically the following: you install solr on a server, you configure a schema (a way to store and index data), import data from you database, and bind your search form to the web service.

You might want to read [this article to have more informations about geolocation searches](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/j-spatial/) (maybe slightly outdated, you'll have to check).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion -- I've come across Solr before though haven't built anything with it -- this sounds like an excellent use case for anyone that needs to keep things inhouse

Comment: Google Geocoding seemed like the way to go until I reviewed the pricing -- 2,500 max queries per day without a business license which gets expensive quick for a non-profit -- guess it'll be multiple fields for now and SOLR later

Answer (score 2):

Recently faced with a similar problem, I have used Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to do this. The nice part is you do not need to parse the address string at all. You just pass it to google and it deals with the parsing. If a location is found, it returns you a structured object describing the address. You can extract any pieces of the address you want.

Of course this solution only works if you have a website and your usage of the geolocation API is allowed by the [Google Maps TOS](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).

Comment: This one will be for a non-profit so this seems like the quickest implementation -- thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've used Google Maps API for various projects before, though upon further review of the TOS the pricing structure will be cost prohibitive. Great idea for smaller use cases though.